# Intersection of linear Transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Good night, i was thinking about this:

If $T(L_{1}+L_{2})=T(L_{1})+T(L_{2})$, then i can work with this:

$T(L_{1}\cap L_{2})=T(L_{1})\cap T(L_{2})$ but I can not think of anything to prove this fact, please help me.

Comment: Can you define $L_1,L_2$ and $T$?

Comment: $T$ is an linear transformation for example:$T(\mathbb{R}^{2})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ @Levent

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ Is an domain an $R$ is the codomain.

Comment: What are $L_1$ and $L_2$?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Vectorial spaces.

Comment: I can see how $T(L_1\cap L_2)\subseteq T(L_1) \cap T(L_2)$ -- just use the definition -- but does the reverse equality necessarily hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove it because it's not correct. For instance, let $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be given by $T(x, y) = x$, let $L_1 = \text{span}\{ (1, 0)\}$ and let $L_2 = \text{span}\{ (1, 1)\}$. Then $T(L_1 \cap L_2) = 0$, while $T(L_1) \cap T(L_2) = \Bbb R$.

Comment: I just came up with that example a minute ago. Kudos.